# Calling signals in angular v17 within the component functions gives error this.signal is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angularv17 component Search like below

```
import { signal } from '@angular/core';

export class SearchComponent {
  public results = signal<Q[]>([]);
  public searchValue = signal('');

  public search() {
    // ... rest of the code

    // throws error here this
    // Error: ERROR TypeError: ctx.searchInputValue is not a function
    this.searchInputValue().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

The problem arises from the input that I have in the template file

```
<input ...other-attr [(ngModel)]="searchInputValue" (input)="search" />
```

What should I do to fix the issue?

I am expecting it to run search function without any difficulties.

Also, I tried to pass [(ngModel)]="searchInputValue()" ngModel like so but it gives another error `Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 20`

Answer (score 0):

try it with the searchInputValue property as a function in the TypeScript file .

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent {
  public results: Q[] = [];
  public searchValue = '';

  public searchInputValue(): string {
    // Add your logic here to return the search input value
    return this.searchValue;
  }

  public search() {
    // ... rest of the code

    // Call the searchInputValue function
    const inputValue = this.searchInputValue().toLowerCase();
    // rest of the code
  }
}
```

and if all workers fine and you stinll need to use signal you can give it a try with it and let us know about any .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the [banana in a box](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) (two way binding) on signals because this will not automatically call `set()/update()` for you.

```
<input ...other-attr [ngModel]="searchInputValue" (input)="search($event)" />
```

When the `search()` method should update the signal.